# visual C++ 2019 next search result key binding

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am completely stumped by this seemingly-simple request: I want a key binding for "go to next item in find results" in Visual Studio 2019 (specifically, Visual Studio 2019 configured for C++).  In earlier VS versions, the F4 key worked for both find results and the error list.  Now these have been separated.  F8 works for the error list but not the find results.  Specifically, I want to:

- Hit Shift-Ctrl-F or choose "find in files"
- See the find results window populated
- Walk through find results by hitting some hotkey

I thought that I found a solution, by binding the `Edit.GoToFindResults1NextLocation` to a hotkey, but that doesn't work.  I've found that come commands need to be bound to the "Text editor" space instead of "Global" to work properly, but doesn't help in this case.

Comment: `F8` works for me; it is also displayed in the tooltip when you hover over that button in the `Find` panel, and in context menu. The command is `Edit.GoToNextLocation`.  Also, I don't see `Edit.GoToFindResultsNextLocation`; there are `Edit.GoToFindResults1NextLocation` and `Edit.GoToFindResults2NextLocation`

Comment: Ah, right!  Edit.GoToNextLocation is the trick.  Somehow my F8 had gotten unbound from that.  If you answer the question I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>F8</kbd> works for me; it is also displayed in the tooltip when you hover over that button in the `Find` panel, and in context menu.

The command is `Edit.GoToNextLocation`.

Also, I don't see `Edit.GoToFindResultsNextLocation`; there are `Edit.GoToFindResults1NextLocation` and `Edit.GoToFindResults2NextLocation`

Comment: Awesome.  @vlad-feinstein perhaps you also know the answer to a related question: when I move mouse over a symbol, hold CTRL and click mouse, it goes to the symbol definition.  I've tried binding a key to Edit.GoToSymbol or Edit.QuickFindSymbol (because my brain is wired for keystrokes), but neither is the same thing.  How can I find out what the command is?

Comment: @Wheezil - I do know that :) - `F12` - `Edit.GoToDefinition` (but it won't work for mouse hover, you need to place cursor in that symbol)

Comment: Thanks!  I find it a lot easier moving between VS and Netbeans if I can get the same key bindings